# Windows Forms Splash screen doesn't display

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, splash-screen

I have a Windows forms project, written in vb.net 2005.

It's all working fine, except that the Splash screen won't show before the frmMain is shown.

In Project properties I have set the Splash screen.
In the Splash screen **Shown** event I have set a delay using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)`

But the main MDI form just loads, and then the Splash screen is obviously behind it as the cursor is showing 'Wait' for a few seconds.

In VS 2005 it used to work beautifully, show the Splash screen for a couple of seconds, then load the main form.

Is there something else I need to do in VS 2008?

thanks

Comment: Using Thread.Sleep() on a thread that displays UI is a very good way to cause random trouble like this.  Windows gets pretty sulky when a window stops responding to messages.  Increase the MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime property value instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks - where is that setting please? I don't see it in Project or frmSplash properties.

Comment: Look here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfkbc5a3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Project --> Properties --> Application Tab --> (Scroll Down to Bottom Right) --> **"View Application Events"** Button, and you should see something like:

```
Namespace My

    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' 
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Now override OnInitialize() and set MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime() as outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.minimumsplashscreendisplaytime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Namespace My

    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' 
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Protected Overrides Function OnInitialize(ByVal commandLineArgs As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)) As Boolean
            ' Set the display time to 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds):
            Me.MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime = 3000
            Return MyBase.OnInitialize(commandLineArgs)
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: I've done that and the Splash screen only shows for less than a second before the main MDI screen shows. If I immediately close the main window, before the application exits I can see the Splash screen behind

Comment: it's really weird that if I run the exe from the \bin\debug folder the Splash screen shows for 3 seconds, with the main form behind it whilst if I run it in the VS 2008 IDE with F5 I get the problem outlines in my previous comment!